# PHP session_start() reads after creating a new session id

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I have a class that implements my own SessionHandlerInterface that stores sessions in a remote Redis server. One thing I noticed is that session_start() always executes a read even if a cookie with name PHPSESSID was NOT recieved. If it just generated a new sessionId, why attempt to check if it exists? Surely it's not present. This seems like an unecessary trip to my Redis session manager. I'm curious if I'm misunderstanding this or if there's a way to override this behavior and only read a session from Redis if a PHPSESSID cookie was received.

Comment: Don't worry about it and keep and working on your project. Your concern sounds like an unnecessary micro optimization :)

Comment: I keep telling myself this but... it bothers me that whenever a user logs in I'm getting double the network traffic and my Redis session manager gets hit twice. I doubt it's going to be an issue for me, but with cloud environments charging for resources I can see this being a potential aggravation for some. I may just add a check to stop the premature read from occurring if a session id was just generated. This just seems like a PHP design flaw to me.